# CGContext: changes the whole view color if i changed the stroke color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I am using different buttons to change the stroke color in UIBezierPath curve drawing using CGContext,but on changing color the lines drawn earlier also changes color according to the last stroke color.But i don't want the earlier drawn lines to change color.
Any help is appreciated.
I have used the following code:

```
(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

if(colorwith==1){
    CGContextRef bluecontext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextBeginPath(bluecontext); // clears any previous path
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(bluecontext, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, .06);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(bluecontext, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextStrokePath(bluecontext); // draw blue line


for(UIBezierPath *_tempPath in _arrayForOperationPath)
{
  [_tempPath strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];      
}
    //[[UIColor blackColor]setStroke];
}
else if (colorwith==2){

    CGContextRef bluecontextt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextBeginPath(bluecontextt); // clears any previous path
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(bluecontextt, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7, .01);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(bluecontextt, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextStrokePath(bluecontextt); 
          // [[UIColor redColor]setStroke];


for(UIBezierPath *_tempPath in _arrayForOperationPath)
{
  [_tempPath strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];      
}
    //[[UIColor blackColor]setStroke];
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

After `CGContextRef bluecontext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();` add `CGContextSaveGState(bluecontext);` and `CGContextRestoreGState(bluecontext);` after you draw your bezier paths.

Your problem is that drawRect is called everytime the context updates...so everytime you draw something. You set the line color here but the previous paths already drawn don't remember RGB..just alpha ( if i remember correctly).

With `CGContextSaveGState` and `CGContextRestoreGState` you save the previous context, draw , and then restore the context as it was plus the drawing you've done.